# Проверка на минимальное значение в форме?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть форма:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('list',
            CollectionType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
            ])
            ->add('price',
            IntegerType::class,
            [
                'required' => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'constraints' => [
                    new GreaterThanOrEqual(50)
                ],
            ]);
    }
```

Как указать тут что число price должно быть больше или равно 0?
Пробовал так:

```
'constraints' => [
                    new GreaterThanOrEqual(50)
                ],
```

Но валидация не работает, пропускает любые числа.

Comment: А какой акшн где Вы проверяете форму?

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk, там я проверяю $form->isValid()

Comment: @KostiantynOkhotnyk и еще форма так:
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductForm::class, null, ['csrf_protection' => false, 'allow_extra_fields' => true]);

Comment: не совсем понял. Вам надо больше нуля, а Вы пишете 50 `new GreaterThanOrEqual(["value" => 0])`

Comment: Метод isValid() не производит валидацию, а выдает вам результат валидации. Сама валидация происходит ЕМНИП где то в дебрях ->submit()
Ну и да, как справедливо заметил @KostiantynOkhotnyk нужно корректно передавать данные. (там на входе массив)

Answer (score 0):

Плохо что Вы не предоставили код в котором обрабатываете форму. Подозреваю что там не хватает примерно такой проверки.

```
  $form->handleRequest($request);      
  if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           //action
        }
```